# How to manage login session in Angular with Spring boot project?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt, angular-guards

I am developing an Angular application with Spring boot.
I have developed a login page that takes **username** and **password** as input.
A web service which authenticates the user from the backend and sends a response with success and failure.
And a homepage that gets displayed after successful authentication.

What's happening is that I can also open the home page URL directly without login and that's not the correct one.

What I need is to implement a mechanism that will checks if the user is logged in or not and based on that it would display a URL page or a login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best practices to handle authentication in web applications is using [JWT](https://jwt.io/)
to generate and check **Token** on the server side and passing token in the communications of Front-end & back-and. When you implement this and after authentication in server, you have to store **Token** in **LocalStorage** or **SessionStorage** or **cockies** for future interactions.

For creating protected routes in Angular application you have to implement these:

- **AuthService** which is a GET API to check the validation of the current token with backend.
- **AuthGuard** which can protect your desired routes using **AuthService** & **CanActivate** property on routes.

Here is a sample code for you:

**app-AuthGuard.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // check if route is restricted by role
            if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
                // role not authorised so redirect to home page
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return false;
            }

            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { User } from '@app/_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`);
    }

    getById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/${id}`);
    }
}
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers';
import { Role } from './_models';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

For more information and complete example read this article:
[Angular 8 - Role Based Authorization Tutorial with Example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/08/06/angular-8-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example)

Comment: Thanks ngHobby !!! This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to bake a `canActivate` route guard into your routing. I'd explain in detail, but this article will probably do a better job: http://gnomeontherun.com/2017/03/02/guards-and-login-redirects-in-angular/

It's job will essentially be to check if a user is logged and redirect if they are not. There's some other nuance stuff like persisting login on navigation to/from the site (often via local storage), but this should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a ton "iamaword'!

Comment: Its very helpful. Can you please suggest how to store the login session as well? Is it safe to use local storage, session storage or cookies? Ir is there a better way exists?

Comment: local storage is the way we do it because you need to have something to keep track of who 'you' are without having to input anything. You could keep a token in local storage and send it up to the backend when you hit the login page, and do your verifications there. That's what we do. We also have a refresh token sent to the backend to ensure the, say 15 minute timer, refreshes so they can navigate around for a long time